# Read Nullable enum from Sql into SqlDataReader Class

Tags: c#, enums, nullable, sqldatareader

Suppose I have enum defined like this:

```
  public enum ServiceType : int
    {
        None= 0,
        TBB= 1,
        Doctor= 2,
        Organization = 3
    }
```

Now, in a class I use it like this:

```
 public Utility.ServiceType ? ServiceType  { get; set; }
```

Now, how would I read values stored in SQL in SqlDataReader Class? 
I tried with

```
ServiceType = reader["ServiceType "] as Utility.ServiceType ?
```

but getting null as a value.

Comment: Should `reader["ServiceType "]` be `reader["ServiceType"]`? The space could be causing problems.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen. Well that is my mistake while I copied code. In my original code there is no space. I solve this problem by putting corresponding field in SQL mandatory with default value '0', so I read value from SQL like this:                 `Enum.Parse(typeof(Utility.ServiceType), reader["ServiceType"].ToString()) as Utility.ServiceType?` but I am still interested in how would I read values from SQL if there is `NULL` values in field named ServiceType.

Answer (score 1):

I should have seen this earlier. My apologies. My bet is that this is an unboxing issue. You might have to do this:

```
var field = reader["ServiceType"];
if (field == DBNull.Value)
    ServiceType = null;
else
    ServiceType = (Utility.ServiceType)(int)field;
```